# How can I modify the range in this macro when I need the values of the next row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code in VBA where a V-Lookup is done if a certain condition is met.
It works fine but now how can I do the same thing to the next row data values without the need to rewrite the code.

```
Sub starting_stock()
If Worksheets("out").Range("E2").Value = "" Then
Set ItemRef = Worksheets("out").Range("A2")
Set MyRange = Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A:G")
Worksheets("out").Range("D2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ItemRef, MyRange, 7, False)
End If
End Sub
```

I want to do the same to D3 with values of E3, A3 without the need to rewrite the code every time.

This is an Stock Control System.

There are two sheets, One is called "Inventory" and the other is called "out".
Field in Inventory : ProductRef,Initial Stock, Stock Out(SUMIF for all Qty Out corresponding to a particular ProductRef), Final Stock.
Field in out : Product Ref, Starting Stock, Qty out, Remaining Stock, Date.

The aim here is to V-lookup the Final Stock from Inventory into Starting Stock if Qty Out is Null and as per the V-Lookup criteria of product Ref.

Remaining Out has a simple formula Starting Stock- Qty Out.

A normal formula cannot be used since any changes made in Qty will affect all previous entries with the same Product Ref.

Starting Stock should be as at date and remain as such.

Comment: Use a formula instead and drag down. I see no reason for VBA in this case

Comment: I have edited my question to bring more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is wrap it in a `For` loop. See below:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub starting_stock()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To 3
        If Worksheets("out").Range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
            Set ItemRef = Worksheets("out").Range("A" & i)
            Set MyRange = Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A:G")
            Worksheets("out").Range("D" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ItemRef, MyRange, 7, False)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Read more about `For` loops here: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-for-loop/

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. But I have an issue with For i=2 To 3 line, You see The data to be V-Lookup will depend on the data entered in ProductRef, so I cannot have a loop run continuously when there won't even be data in the Product Ref column

Comment: Thanks to your input. I just modified your code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you are looking for:
You want to select a cell in a column and run the code and it will use value of the A column on the same row to perform the vlookup and paste the value in D column with the same row?

In that case ActiveCell.row is probably what you need.

```
Sub starting_stock()
    If Worksheets("out").Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "" Then
        Set ItemRef = Worksheets("out").Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row)
        Set MyRange = Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A:G")
        Worksheets("out").Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ItemRef, MyRange, 7, False)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting. The code works if the cell is selected by user. If not,an error message is displayed. What do you think of my answer?

Comment: I can't say that the question relates to the answer in any way.

Comment: I just figured that in addition to  checking if E(qty out) cell is Null, the condition also checks if A is null in the While loop. If there is a data, it enters the loop and the If statement for V-Lookup. If not, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following solution:

```
Sub Button_Click()

 Dim i As Integer

i = 2

Do While Worksheets("out").Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

        If Worksheets("out").Range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
            Set ItemRef = Worksheets("out").Range("A" & i)
            Set MyRange = Worksheets("Current Inventory").Range("F:M")
            Worksheets("out").Range("D" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ItemRef, MyRange, 8, False)
        End If
i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

A while loop with the condition of not empty ProductRef.